# Golang - post request are not sent in parallel

Tags: go, goroutine

I wanna send several parallel POST requests and save the results, but as I can see the processing is not parallel.

```
func process(
    provider models.Provider, 
    query models.Query, 
    db *sql.DB, 
    ch chan<- models.SocketResource
) {
   body, raw, err := types.PostJSON(urlStr, string(jsonData), map[string]string{"Content-Type": "application/json"}, types.Proxy{}, jar)
   response := models.RequestAnswers{}
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &response)
   ch<- response
}

func getList() {
   ch := make(chan models.SocketResource)
   for _, provider := range providers {
     go process(provider, query, db, ch)
   }
   var answers []models.SocketResource
   for range providers {
     start := time.Now()
     log.Printf("Start time: %s", start)
     res := <-ch
     answers = append(answers, res)
   }
}
```

This code usually works ~ 30s, but I expect near 5 seconds. I've logged start time and received such data:

```
2023/02/20 15:58:41 Start time: 2023-02-20 15:58:41.852120551 +0300 +03 m=+10.902878529
2023/02/20 15:58:41 Start time: 2023-02-20 15:58:41.86559013 +0300 +03 m=+10.916348048
2023/02/20 15:58:41 Start time: 2023-02-20 15:58:41.866299284 +0300 +03 m=+10.91705718
22023/02/20 15:58:46 Start time: 2023-02-20 15:58:46.713829448 +0300 +03 m=+15.764587376
2023/02/20 15:58:57 Start time: 2023-02-20 15:58:57.952024136 +0300 +03 m=+27.002782084
2023/02/20 15:59:06 Start time: 2023-02-20 15:59:06.014041727 +0300 +03 m=+35.064799666
2023/02/20 15:59:06 Start time: 2023-02-20 15:59:06.384299333 +0300 +03 m=+35.435057271
2023/02/20 15:59:06 Start time: 2023-02-20 15:59:06.778590117 +0300 +03 m=+35.829348065
2023/02/20 15:59:11 Start time: 2023-02-20 15:59:11.866662932 +0300 +03 m=+40.917420830
2023/02/20 15:59:11 Start time: 2023-02-20 15:59:11.866689523 +0300 +03 m=+40.917447421
```

If I add more providers, the gap between first and last is usually ~30 seconds

Comment: You're sure the server can handle parallel requests?

Comment: If you mean the server I send request to, I sure it can

Comment: Why are you ranging over providers (in the 2nd loop) instead of the channel?

Comment: You can be sure that `go process(provider, query, db, ch)` executes `process` concurrently, else Go the language would be a scam. If the rest of your program is causing the requests not to be sent concurrently then maybe you should share that part of the program. The bottleneck could be anywhere inside `types.PostJSON` or in its dependencies.

Comment: I'm not good in go, and found this code as an example, I do not know is it good code, but if you know is not, you can provide proper

Comment: I've commented other code but the result was the same, so I think the problem is in this code

Comment: @mkopriva, How will it work, if external server cannot process this amount of requests? I would expect to see the same start time in logs, but different end time, because requests should be sent together and responses can be received in different times.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @vdkt You are correct, however you are logging the start time in the wrong place. `<-ch` is a blocking operation, meaning it will proceed only after a corresponding `ch<- ...` statement is executed, which, in your case, would be **after** `types.PostJSON` is finished (the last statement in process)... So basically your start-logs are waiting for a request process to finish first. In effect you are not logging process starts, but rather process ends.

Comment: Does it mean, the request was sent in loop(like create promise in JS), and then I'm only waiting for result via `ch<-`?

Comment: @vdkt yes, something like that. Just take a look at this playground example: https://go.dev/play/p/bmWHOb_U8Au run it a couple times and see if it makes sense. Do you see how the "starts" are immediately printed? And the "ends" only when the "computation" is done? And do you see how the _receive_ operation `<-ch` is in sync with the "ends"?